# isotope jquery asp MVC, how to trigger the change in layout

Tags: jquery, razor, jquery-isotope

I am working on integrating a plugin for Isotope.js into ASP.NET MVC using the site example. (noobie here, coming from ASP.NET webforms. So, I am new to jquery and plugins.)

Question:

1. Once the data is populated in HTML a nested DIV tag, **I dont see the behavior, how do I trigger the layout/bricking?**. (let me add, it renders differently in Firefox, thank IE9)
2. Javascript error - **Object doesn't support property or method 'isotope'**, but when I trace through, I see its defined in the isotope.js
3. How do I go between layouts, from the html links?

Steps - I followed:

- I have setup the partial views, to invoke/include the js scripts.
- I set up the various data-filter, css classes for filtering (from the iso sample).
- I created a simple iso.js that holds the js script for item selector, layout (script listed below in a separate file), based on the 2 steps in webpage introduction and included/invoked the script after

  1. Jquery
  2. isotope
  3. Css was setup

     ```
     $(function () {
         $('#container').isotope({
         itemSelector: '.element',
         layoutMode: 'fitRows' });
     });
     ```

so, please tell me what else do I need to do?

- I created an anchor `<a>` like below

  ```
  <ul id="filters" class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">
      <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">show all</a></li>
      <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".metal">metals</a></li>
  </ul>
  ```

The data is below - copied straight from the site.

```
  <div class="clickable clearfix isotope" id="container" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 1320px;">

     <div data-category="alkaline-earth" data-symbol="Mg" class="element alkaline-earth metal    width2 height2 isotope-item large" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate(5px, 5px);">
     <p class="number">12</p>
     <h3 class="symbol">Mg</h3>
     <h2 class="name">Magnesium</h2>
     <p class="weight">24.305</p>
     </div>    

  <div data-category="actinoid" data-symbol="U" class="element actinoid metal inner-             transition    width2 isotope-item large" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate(365px, 5px);">
  <p class="number">92</p>
  <h3 class="symbol">U</h3>
  <h2 class="name">Uranium</h2>
  <p class="weight">238.02891</p>
</div>

  </div>
```

So, please let me know what am I missing and if my sequence of steps is missing something.

Comment: First, the trigger did not occur because in MVC 4, if you use nuget as i did to update, there are two jquery includes in one page. bundle/jquery and another jquery.ver.min.js